# launching browsers from the commandline

Tags: protractor

pretty new to protractor but this one has me stumped.
Running Angular 1.5.0 on windows 10.

I want to be able to override the browser specified in my config.js file from the command line.  After digging about I found that using the following was how to do it:
protractor --capabilities.browserName='x' config.js

however, if I try to use firefox, then chrome is launched, if I try to launch IE (using --capabilities.browserName='internet explorer' then I get an error about only having one config file.

I also tried putting in rubbish as a browser name and chrome launched - so looks like chrome is the default, from using selenium I had to specify the path to the IE driver server (and actually the chrome driver) - is protractor the same?

For reference the following is the config file - it's pretty basic (like I said I am still learning protractor)

var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',


specs: ['LA1-310-Q4.js'],

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',

onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: 'reports2/'
    }).getJasmine2Reporter());
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working.  It seems I wasn't aware of how important quotes were.

so using:
`protractor --capabilities.browserName='firefox'  config.js`
started chrome, however changing this to:
`protractor --capabilities.browserName=firefox config.js`
launched firefox.  For Internet Explorer, I had to use double quotes.  Sorted now.